# Entity Framework Core: Class entity inheritance to add navigation property - Avoid discriminator column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 3.1 I created a new entity class that inherits from an existing entity in my data model. These classes exist in different solutions so that's why I have to make this change through inheritance and not by simply modifying the original entity.

**The only intent of this inheritance is to add a new navigation property for a new many to many relationship that I created.**

By default, Entity Framework is creating a new Discriminator column which makes sense for most cases but not in this one. Please notice that I am not adding new fields through my child class, the schema remains unchanged. I just want to have a navigation property for that new relationship which is represented by a join table.

```
/// Original entity
public class LineItemEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PriceId { get; set; }
 
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

/// My entity adding the new navigation property
public class CustomOrderLineItemEntity : LineItemEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Order item proofs related to the order line item
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<OrderItemProofEntity> OrderItemProofs { get; set; } 
        = new List<OrderItemProofEntity>();
}
```

The issue I have is that when I use the repository that references the child (**CustomOrderLineItemEntity**) all of my queries are going to the database with a where clause `WHERE [o].[Discriminator] = N'CustomOrderLineItemEntity'` and I am suspecting this is making all my queries fail as there are no entities with that value set in the Discriminator, and most probably they will never be as the inserts will remain to happen with the Parent entity (**LineItemEntity**) not the child.

Is there any way to force EF to don't create the discriminator for a case like the one I am describing or is there a better way to approach what I need to do?

Comment: What you are doing is somewhat non-standard... Look at it from your DB side.. If you have a LineItem record, how do you determine whether that row should, or should not have OrderItemProofs? The answer to that question would be what you need to use as the discriminator.  If the answer is that any LineItem could have them, that they are optional, then you shouldn't be creating a subclass, just have them off the LineItem.

Comment: @StevePy Everything you said is correct. The reason why it "has to be" through inheritance is because the classes are in different solutions. I can't go and modify that base code, the only thing I can do is extend that base code including its entities.

And the join table is basically a new entity for a many to many relationship. There are no modifications needed to the tables involved in the join. Which LineItems have OrderItemProofs should be implied by the relationship. They can have many or none.